# Mongo pageable search with different criteria in springboot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, aggregation-framework

I need to build a search result with a pagination feature. Each page should show 5 search results and the first page should show,

```
1 promo item
3 featured item
remains should be random items (it is changed order every time)
```

The sample result set should show like this

1st page

```
item 1 (promo item)
item 2 (featured item)
item 3 (featured item)
item 4 (featured item)
item 5
```

2nd page

```
item 6
item 7
item 8
item 9
item 10
```

I was able to create a mongo query by using the mongo facet. But I'm using AWS DocumentDB and it's not supporting the facet option. I tried using the spring data (mongo template) facet option as well. but that doesn't work as I expected.

Is there any better solution or approach for this kind of search result feature? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't just use `MongoTemplate` and handle the first page with promo item logic?

Comment: Few months ago, i tried to update to AWS Documentdb from mongo db, A lot of operations are not supported by Documentdb... So we kept in mongodb https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html

Comment: @geobreze how do I handle promo and featured items at once? even though I handle those two criteria. how do I exclude first page items from my second page and so on?